# "/me/joinedTeams" does not return my team

Tags: microsoft-teams

My service invoke graph API `POST /groups/{groupId}/owners` to add myself into a new team. After that, I use `GET /me/joinedTeams` on my local machine, but it does not return the team which I just joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember, there is a known issue that if you add a user as an owner, you should add the user as a member as well. Otherwise, some APIs' behavior might not meet your expectation.

Comment: Found it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta#membership-changes-in-microsoft-teams